# How to check how much session expiry time is left? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-sessions

With **"views.py"** as shown below, I'm trying to check **how much session expiry time is left** by setting **"60" seconds expiry time** but after **"20" seconds sleep**, [**get_expiry_age()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age), [**get_session_cookie_age()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_session_cookie_age) and [**get_expiry_date()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_date) didn't return **"40" seconds expiry time which is expected**:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render
import time

def test(request):
    request.session.set_expiry(60) # "60" seconds expiry time is set

    time.sleep(20) # Sleep for "20" seconds

    print(request.session.get_expiry_age())         # 60
    print(request.session.get_session_cookie_age()) # 1209600 
    print(request.session.get_expiry_date())        # 2022-08-07 00:34:41.700828+00:00
    
    return render(request, 'test/index.html')
```

So, are there any ways to check **how much session expiry time is left**?

Comment: Was looking for something similar. Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think while it is in your view expiry_age of original request won't get updated and It will get Updated after your response passes the `process_response` in  `SessionMiddleware`.
If you check the source code you see this
in [set_expiry](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L250) it sets the value in self['_session_expiry'] = value.

```py
def set_expiry(self, value):
    """
    Set a custom expiration for the session. ``value`` can be an integer,
    a Python ``datetime`` or ``timedelta`` object or ``None``.

    If ``value`` is an integer, the session will expire after that many
    seconds of inactivity. If set to ``0`` then the session will expire on
    browser close.

    If ``value`` is a ``datetime`` or ``timedelta`` object, the session
    will expire at that specific future time.

    If ``value`` is ``None``, the session uses the global session expiry
    policy.
    """
    if value is None:
        # Remove any custom expiration for this session.
        try:
            del self['_session_expiry']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return
    if isinstance(value, timedelta):
        value = timezone.now() + value
    self['_session_expiry'] = value
```

and then in [get_expiry_age](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L200) is uses the same key if it exist to show you expiry age.

```py
def get_expiry_age(self, **kwargs):
    """Get the number of seconds until the session expires.

    Optionally, this function accepts `modification` and `expiry` keyword
    arguments specifying the modification and expiry of the session.
    """
    try:
        modification = kwargs['modification']
    except KeyError:
        modification = timezone.now()
    # Make the difference between "expiry=None passed in kwargs" and
    # "expiry not passed in kwargs", in order to guarantee not to trigger
    # self.load() when expiry is provided.
    try:
        expiry = kwargs['expiry']
    except KeyError:
        expiry = self.get('_session_expiry')

    if not expiry:   # Checks both None and 0 cases
        return self.get_session_cookie_age()
    if not isinstance(expiry, datetime):
        return expiry
    delta = expiry - modification
    return delta.days * 86400 + delta.seconds
```

if you set the expiry in a view and return a response the new expiry age will be visible in all the requests after that but you can't use it in the same view before your `SessionMiddleware` has processed it.